# How to display data from mysql table as ListView in android app

Tags: android, mysql

I have a user table in the MySQL database, and I want to read the data and display it on android as a ListView, and on clicking each item it must display the complete information about it.

Comment: At list try to do some code whatever you know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. You have to create a servlet that allows you to access the data from the MySQL table
> 2. The servlet will eb called using a JSONParser from your app by passing the URL of the servlet to the JSONParser
> 3. You will need to convert your servlet side data to JSON for easy retrieval and mapping in the android app (Use the HTTP components jar
>      file for this)
> 4. Once you have got and successfully parsed the data you can call each individual field within the JSON and set it in the Listview xml
>      elements
> 5. To open another activity on click of the listview you implement the onItemClick to pass your data to the next activity via intents
>
> Some links that were useful for me:
>   http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
>   http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/
>   http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/UseGETorPOSTtocommunicatewithaJavaservlet.htm
>   http://qa.java-samples.com/questions/827/connecting-servlet-using-android
>   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-database-access.htm
>   [Create json object in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364036/create-json-object-in-servlet)
>
> Hope it goes well